copy skompile model to clipboard
I have a random forest model that I've trained in Python 3.11.0 with scikit-learn. I'm then exporting the model weights with skompiler 0.7. I then export the model weights to dataframe, and then copy to clipboard.  I have pyperclip 1.8.2 installed.  I've installed xclip and xsel on my ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS server that I'm running my code on.  I'm getting the error below when I run the code in a cell in a jupyter notebook I'm hosting from my ubuntu server.  Do you know what the issue might be and can you suggest how to solve it?
code:
from skompiler import skompile
from skompiler.fromskast.excel import excel_range

expr = skompile(rf.predict,excel_range(f"B3:BQ3")

code = expr.to('excel', multistage=True, assign_to=exccel_range('BT3:*3'))

code.to_dataframe().to_clipboard()

error:
PyperclipException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[48], line 1
----> 1 code.to_dataframe().to_clipboard()

File /anaconda/envs/channels/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:333, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    327 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    328     warnings.warn(
    329         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    330         FutureWarning,
    331         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    332     )
--> 333 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/channels/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:3244, in NDFrame.to_clipboard(self, excel, sep, **kwargs)
    3177 r"""
    3178 Copy object to the system clipboard.
    3179 
    (...)
    3240    pyperclip.copy(html)
    3241 """
    3242 from pandas.io import clipboards
-> 3244 clipboards.to_clipboard(self, excel=excel, sep=sep, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/channels/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboards.py:178, in to_clipboard(obj, excel, sep, **kwargs)
    175     obj.to_csv(buf, sep=sep, encoding="utf-8", **kwargs)
    176     text = buf.getvalue()
--> 178     clipboard_set(text)
    179     return
    180 except TypeError:

File /anaconda/envs/channels/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboard/__init__.py:659, in lazy_load_stub_copy(text)
    657 global copy, paste
    658 copy, paste = determine_clipboard()
--> 659 return copy(text)

File /anaconda/envs/channels/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboard/__init__.py:316, in init_no_clipboard.<locals>.ClipboardUnavailable.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    315 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 316     raise PyperclipException(EXCEPT_MSG)

PyperclipException: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit
    https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#not-implemented-error


Since you are using a remote machine, you may want to see here and here. Persondally, I just usually save the dataframe to CSV (or my preferred TSV) and then download it from the remote machine using the download feature in the file browser in the Jupyter session connected to the remote computer. That saves it to my local machine. You probably want them locally as a file anyway and so that solves multiple issues in the chain or procurring.
